# How can I control transitions from js involving a class change?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, css-transitions

I'm writing a gallery, where when the user clicks on an image, a modal pops up with the image and it's description. Everything works as expected except for the transition. The js successfully activates the `darkened-modal` class shown below, but it doesn't happen over 5 seconds which i tried to do using the css for `#modal`.

My Code:

html

```
        <div id = "modal" class = "closed">
            <div id = "modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```css
#modal {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 5s;
}

#modal.darkened-modal {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px) saturate(40%);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.486); 
}

#modal.closed {
    display: none;
}
```

js

```js
function ImageClicked(image){
    modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    modal.classList.add("darkened-modal"); // dims the background
    modal.classList.remove("closed"); // unhides the modal
}

function OverlayClicked() {
    modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    modal.classList.add("closed");
    modal.classList.remove("darkened-modal");
}

document.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function(event) {
        modal = document.getElementById("modal");
        if (
            event.target.matches("#modal")
        ) {
            modal.classList.toggle("closed");
        }
    },
    false)
```

Comment: Please bring your code to the state of a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: is that better @imvhost?

Comment: No, not better. Can I reproduce your problem now?

Comment: can you be more specific. I'm confused, do you want more or less code? I'm not sure how much i need to put in here. would a link to the github repository be better?